# Why does 子 often default to male in compunds?

Tags: compounds

Was it just assumed if sex of the subject was not stated the subject would be male or is there a different reason?

Comment: Which compounds? I can think of any with especially weighted gender, and on its own like あの子 it leans female

Comment: @angelos 太子, some job titles

Comment: In the case of 帰国子女, if I remember correctly the 子 points to male because that 子 is actually a shortened version of 息子.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure at what level you are asking *why*, but dictionaries state that 子 sometimes man specifically.

> [子](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/kanji/%E5%AD%90/)
>
> ④**おとこ**。「男子」 ⑤**成人した男子**の敬称。特に、地位のある人や学徳のすぐれた人に対する敬称。「君子」「孔子」「夫子」

> [子](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%AD%90)
>
> 1. 男女の間に生まれた者。または、それ同様に育てられた者。または、そのような者と同様の責務を負う者（対義語　親：おや）
>
>    **1.そのうちの男。むすこ。**（対義語　女：むすめ）

Etymologically, it should be more or less because of the male centric nature of older times, just like most Western words for male counterpart being markerless (as in *prince/princess*).